# javascript search for bulletpoint using indexOf

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a string that contains several bullet points (•) that I need to access using the javascript indexOf method. I tried just `indexOf(•)` and `indexOf(U+2022)`, the unicode value, and still am having a -1 return value.

How would I access the bullet points within the string using indexOf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong unicode syntax:

```
someString.indexOf('\u2022');
```

Also, recheck that you're using the correct unicode value for the bullet within the string.

Comment: Apparently not beautifully enough to earn you the coveted green checkmark.  Sorry, zzzzBov ;)

Comment: @ajax81, you have to wait 15 mins before marking an accepted answer, this question is only 10 mins old.

Comment: @zz: Ah, you're right.  Egg's on my face for that one. /sad trombone/

Comment: @ajax81 yea i fully hit the green right away but it told me to wait - thanks for your help!